# Vuex commit not working without payload parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to commit my global action. To access it I have to use `rootState`, so I have to add the root option parameter while commiting. It works if I pass `null` as second parameter, which is **payload**, but it doesn't work if I leave it empty.

Working version:

```
context.commit('shared/clearError', null, { root: true })
```

Not working:

```
context.commit('shared/clearError, { root: true })
```

So the question is why it don't work without second parameter if it is optional as mentioned in their [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#commit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can commit mutations with either one of these methods:

- `commit(mutation: Object, options?: Object)`
- `commit(type: string, payload?: any, options?: Object)`

You are mixing them up: You select the mutation by using a string, so it picks the second method which has three params. Your options object is picked as the payload and probably does not have the data your mutation expects.

This should work as you expect:

```
context.commit({ type: 'shared/clearError'}, { root: true })
```

(Also, you are missing the closing quote in the second statement, but I guess this is just a typo)

For more details see https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html and https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#vuex-store-instance-methods

Comment: Thank you for explaining, it all makes sense now. And yes, the missing quote was a typo.